# curl request not working on centOS but working on Ubuntu

Tags: curl, centos

I'm actually trying to get data from our erp to send it to an API, with curl.

I prepared it on an ubuntu 18.04 server but I need to use this from a centOs 7.5 server now.

The curl command is working well on the ubuntu server but gives me no answer when called from the centOs. 
I thought it was a curl installation issue but curl commands are working well when I try to call other URLs (like wttr.in). 
Our ERP authorizes incoming connections from this server. The $targetUrl calls a java servlet that returns json data.

this is my php curl request:

```
public function getOraclecustomersInfos()
    {
        $ch = curl_init($targetUrl);

        $vars = 'action=devis';
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars);

        $content = curl_exec( $ch );
        $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
        $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
        $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );

        curl_close( $ch );

        $oracleCustomersInfosJson = json_decode($content, true);
        return $oracleCustomersInfosJson;
    }
```

This should return a list of customers, but returns absolutly nothing, no error and no content.

The last thing I think that can generate the issue is something with Access-Control-Allow-Origin but I really don't know how to check this....

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the problem came from the ERP itself. To access the Java servlet I needed to have the new server IP authorized.

Problem solved